# No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.replaceAll()

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0

I have code like this:

```
soData =
        [   deviceId:so.deviceId,
            deviceName:so.deviceName,
            description:so.description,
        ]



soData.each() { key, value ->
    if(value=="null"|| value==null){
        deviceData.put(key, "")
    }
}



soData?.deviceName?.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9. _-]+","").replaceAll(" ", "_")
```

And I am getting error like this **inconsistently**

```
No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.replaceAll() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [[^a-zA-Z0-9. _-]+, ]. Stacktrace follows:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.replaceAll() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [[^a-zA-Z0-9. _-]+, ]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `so.deviceName` is an `ArrayList` which has no `replaceAll()` method. Please show how you obtain this value or just try to get first item from this list if you're sure that it should be only one value (with: `deviceName[0]`).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In my actual code there is some conditions around first block of code, so that conditions are failing and it returning empty[] list some times, and so the problem occurs.